# calculate difference between dates in same column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datediff

I am trying to calculate difference between dates in same column and so far unsuccessful.
Here is the data that I am using and here is the code that I did so far. I provided script for your reference.  Hopefully it helps.

```
CREATE TABLE Test (Product varchar (250), Orderdate Datetime );
insert into TEST (product, orderdate) 
values ('A', '2019/01/01'), ('B', '2019/01/11'),  ('C', '2019/01/15'),  ('D', '2019/01/20');
```

Script I am running and getting actual result.

```
SELECT  t.Product,  t.orderdate,    
        datediff(day,t2.orderdate,t.orderdate) as diffdays  
FROM TEST t  
  join test t2 on t2.product = t.product
```

Below is desired result:

```
Product Orderdate   Diffdays
A       1/1/2019        0
B       1/11/2019       10
C       1/15/2019       4
D       1/20/2019       5
```

Actual result:

```
Product orderdate   diffdays
A       1/1/2019          0
B       1/11/2019         0
C       1/15/2019         0
D       1/20/2019         0
```

Comment: It would be helpful to other users if you accepted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have only one row for each product, so if you join on it, you'll be joining the same row with itself, resulting in a datediff of zero, as you've seen.

Instead, you could `lag` the `orderdate` according to the `product`, and use that for the datediff:

```
SELECT   product,
         orderdate,
         COALESCE(DATEDIFF(DAY, overdate, LAG(overdate) OVER (ORDER BY product)),0)
FROM     test
ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try lag function:

```
SELECT 
product,
ISNULL(
   DATEDIFF(DAY, lag(orderdate,1) OVER (ORDER BY orderdate), orderdate),0) AS DIF
FROM TEST
ORDER BY PRODUCT
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.product, 
       t.orderdate, 
       IsNull(Datediff(day, Lag(t.orderdate, 1) 
                              OVER ( 
                                ORDER BY t.orderdate), t.orderdate), 0) 
FROM   test t
```

Comment: This works! Thank you very much! i will learn about lag functions as many of you used it to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

The Below Query will satisfy your problem.

```
SELECT X.Product,X.Orderdate,ISNULL(DATEDIFF(DAY,X.PREVDATE,X.Orderdate),0) AS DayDiff FROM (SELECT T.Product,T.Orderdate, LAG(T.Orderdate) OVER( ORDER BY ORDERDATE) AS PREVDATE  FROM Test T )X
```